# Rotate a line in libGdx

Tags: rotation, libgdx

How to rotate a line made by ShapeRenderer from line's center using LibGdx.

I read shape renderer Class code from documentation provided but its for Rectangle.

I am somehow able to rotate  line but not getting how its roatating and how to rotate from centre

Answer (score 1):

Try and use the ShapeRenderer.rotate() method.

```
public void rotate(float axisX,
      float axisY,
      float axisZ,
      float angle)
```

In a 2d game you would leave the z axis alone but change the rest.

```
//init
ShapeRenderer sr = new ShapeRenderer();
//in your render
void render(){
    //draw the line
    sr.rotate(paramaters);
}
```